# in app billing in android using titanium studio

Tags: android, titanium, in-app-billing, titanium-modules

am building an in app billing application for android using titanium studio. I've found a module and I've successfully included it in my app. But don't know what to do next. Am new to this in app billing.Can anyone tell me that what should I do next or is there any documentation of this android module.
here is the link of module
[Module Link](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/776#!overview)
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks:)

Comment: have you read the documentation or checked out the examples that comes along with that module?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first download the module. Once you do that, you can unzip it and navigate through the unzipped folders to the documentation folder. The structure should be something like this:

android/ti.inappbilling/2.2.1/documentation

Not that documentation is of much help, but its a starting place.